# How to insert a record with id (auto increment) PostgREST?

Tags: postgresql, vuejs2, axios, postgrest

I have a function

```
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/unitsmeasure', {
            id: 20,
            name: 'name'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

It inserts an entry in the table. Its works.

But when I do not specify the id it does not work. id (serial PRIMARY KEY).

```
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/unitsmeasure', {
            name: 'name'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

This does not work

SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "unitsmeasure" (
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" varchar(100)
)
```

SQL Dump:

```
CREATE TABLE "unitsmeasure" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Request".unitsmeasure_id_seq'::regclass),
  "name" varchar(100) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default"
);
ALTER TABLE "unitsmeasure" OWNER TO "postgres";

ALTER TABLE "unitsmeasure" ADD CONSTRAINT "unitsmeasure_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");
```

Comment: Can you show the SQL you used to create the table?

Comment: Update your Question, dont post code in the comments! :)

Comment: @StefanE Update

Comment: Normally Quotation marks is not needed for the create statement and not sure if this is actually affecting the service. Try the Create without them around table name and id & name.

Comment: Can you add the error message you are getting as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely culprit is not having granted usage permissions to the sequence.

Try this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE unitsmeasure_id_seq TO user_name;
```

The inserting user needs access to the sequence in order to insert a value from the sequence.